# Understanding this custom event handler and unity3d

Tags: events, unity-game-engine

I'm still new to C# I use Unity3d. I'm wanting to learn about events, I've been reading on them and have the gist of them. My friend recommended me to use this event handler in unity

http://www.willrmiller.com/?p=87

But I really don't know how to use it because.

1. None of it derives from MonoBehaviour, so how could I trigger the event with a keypress or a Unity condition when it's not deriving from Unity?
2. In the event class SomethingHappenedEvent I don't even know what parameters would go in there, because I'm new to events. My guess would be a condition like if a key is pressed or something in Unity happened. But that goes back to 1: it doesn't derive from MonoBehavior so I don't know how to do that.
3. To sum it up how is this event system even getting ran because Unity3d from what I've done so far requires a script to be on a GameObject.

So can someone tell me how to get this working in Unity and better understand events, especially in Unity3d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> None of it derives from monobehavior, so how could I trigger the event with a keypress or a unity condition when its not deriving from unity?

As the post states, you use

```c#
Events.instance.Raise(new SomethingHappenedEvent());
```

That is, if something happens (your keypress or a certain condition) **you** raise the event. You tell the manager that something happened, and it will take care of telling all interested parties (the listeners) about it.

From reading your question I assume that is your primary source of confusion. This code will not automagically connect to any events. What it does is provide a framework for you to put events into. And you can specify when objects should listen to which events. Then the framework will take care of informing all the listeners whenever an event happens that they might be interested in. An event that you raise.

This is useful in the sense that you don't have to find those objects/entities/GameObjects that you want to notify. Nor do you have to use broadcast messages or solutions like that.

> In the event class SomethingHappenedEvent I don't even know what parameters would go in there, because I'm new to events, my guess would be a condition like if a key is pressed or something in unity happened.

Whatever you want really. You are creating your own event. So what information is relevant for your own event? Is it a HitEvent, where you want to know which enemy was hit? Then store the enemy. Is there an event where location is important? Then store the location. It's up to you.

> To sum it up how is this event system even getting ran because unity3d from what I've done so far requires a script to be on a gameobject.

This class relies on the concept of a [singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx). It has a static instance. This will be initialized whenever you call your `Events.instance.Raise(new SomethingHappenedEvent());`for the first time. From wherever you call it. The relevant code here is

```c#
public static Events instance
{
    get
    {
        if (eventsInstance == null)
        {
            eventsInstance = new Events();
        }

        return eventsInstance;
    }
}
```

That is, when trying to get the instance, if it's not created yet create it and then return it. If it was already created, then just return the existing instance. There is no requirement to make this a component and add it to a GameObject.

Comment: Ok you helped me understand it a little better. So you're are saying I should make an **extra** script that derives from mono behave that has conditions that raise an event? Like a EventConditionManager.cs? Also can you give me a example in code of something that could go in the event as a parameter, I'm confused on that as well. Thanks a lot so far!

Comment: Ok I got it working by making a EventTriggerManager.cs that derives from monobehavior so I can trigger any event from a keypress or whatever I want. I Am still confused on what can go in the event parameters though. Could you post a code example please? Like as a test I am just changing the color of a cubes material at the moment when the event is called, what could I put in the event itself as a parameter.

Comment: Well, let's say you have a red, green and blue button. When clicking on those, you want to change the cube's color to red, green or blue. Create your event (say a ColorEvent) which holds an arbitrary color. When clicking on the red cube, you assign it Color.red. And similar for green or blue. Then all your listener needs to do is get whatever color is stored in the ColorEvent and assign that to the cube.